# Manipulating attributes with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently learning web development with CSS, HTML and JavaScript.

This is my code:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#players li');
console.log(items[0], items[1], items[2]);
```

```html
<section id="players">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test2</li>
    <li>Test3</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

What I want to do is to make a specific list item, let's say the third one to have a specific color. I can't figure out to how to use the `style` property to set the CSS-property `color` externally in my JavaScript file.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you know you can achieve your question with CSS only? Is that okay?

Comment: Something like `items[2].style.color = 'red';` to have your third element in red color. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Comment: Yes that is okay.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply `color` through the JavaScript [`style`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp) property, e.g.:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#players li');
if (items.length > 2) {
  items[2].style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<section id="players">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test2</li>
    <li>Test3</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Or you can achieve the same result just with the CSS [`nth-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector:

```css
#players li:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="players">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test2</li>
    <li>Test3</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate `items` using `forEach` and check the `index`. Since the collection starts with `0` for third one you need to check if current index is `2` then use `classList.add` to add a class and style it

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#players li');
items.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index === 2) {
    item.classList.add('custom')
  }
})
```

```css
.custom {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section id="players">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test2</li>
    <li>Test3</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Comment: Doing a `forEach` has a *O(n)*-complexity. Since the index is known in advance, you could simply work with `items[2]` (*O(1)*).

Comment: How do I use this for-loop to iterate through `list-item` to use the `style-property` on these elements to set `text-decoration` to `underline`?